# Android GCM: display message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

When I send message via GCM, it appears on notificationbar without any problem. If I click this notification to show it in an activity; it doesnt display message.

BUT if I start my activity (NotificationDisplay), then send messsage, my messages display.

So how can I show my notification message in **notstarted** activity.

(I think problem may be "registerReceiver" : its in NotificationDisplay onCrate; so cant register if activity not started? )

GCMIntentService:

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("msg"); 

       Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        generateNotification(context, message);

    }

 private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationPage.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity            

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;


        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }
```

NotificationDisplay Activity:

```
@Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.notification_page);         

                lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

                registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                        DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
            }

public final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                     newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
                    // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
                    WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

                    /**
                     * Take appropriate action on this message
                     * depending upon your app requirement
                     * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
                     * */

                    // Showing received message
                    lblMessage.setText(newMessage + "\n");
                // lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");            
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Releasing wake lock
                    WakeLocker.release();
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if onCreate is called or not..if it is getting called each time you click on notification of notification area, then replace the code:

```
`PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0)`
```

with

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

If onCreate is not getting called then try to update the text on onResume or onNewIntent method. Let me know if your issue is resolved

Comment: I have the same issue as the original poster. How can I figure out if my onCreate is getting called? I did add "PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT" in my GCMIntentservice. Also I have no idea how to update my onResume method to receive the intent there.

Comment: Try to do log in onCreate/onResume/onNewIntent and let me know which is getting called?

Comment: learning how to create the logs, will report back once I figure it out.

Comment: Use the Log class in Util package.....

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLogging/article.html

Comment: Ok, so did the log thing, and it does call onCreate when I press on the notification bar message. Maybe I should start a new question so I can post my code as well.

Comment: yeah please post the code of oncreate as well as the code where you are making the Notification.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866895/the-gcm-notification-message-from-the-notification-bar-will-not-be-shown-in-the I started this question. Can you please have a look? SO banned me for making comments. It's funny, I didn't even ask questions lately so it must be because of posting questions.

Comment: wait for few moments... I will have to take a look on your code and get back to you ASAP