# The GCM Notification message from the Notification Bar will not be shown in the activity if the app isn't started already

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using this tutorial for push notifications http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

It works fine but when I click on the status bar to see the received message, it doesn't show in the MainActivity which it starts. What is the issue?

MainActivity which receives the message

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate?");
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }



        // Getting name from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        pid= i.getStringExtra("pid");


        // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

        // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
        // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

        // Get GCM registration id
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

        // Check if regid already presents
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not registered, key is empty ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);

        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "else key is not empty ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Device is already registered on GCM
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                // Skips registration.              

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                final Context context = this;
                mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // Register on our server
                        // On server creates a new user
                        ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId, flat, admin, dummy);
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mRegisterTask = null;
                    }

                };
                mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
            }

        }
        //get info from sqlite database
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        //TextView textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map = db.getUserDetails();
        String username = map.get("email");


        if (username == null){
            a=name;

            movies = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            new GetDaPid().execute();

            // Closing dashboard screen
            //finish();
        }else{

        b=username;

        }
        movies = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        if (repid==null){

            new GetDaPid().execute();
        }else{
            new GetDaComments().execute();
        }




    }   
    class GetDaComments extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
           }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            }

              protected void onPostExecute(String zoom){
                  zpDialog.dismiss();

                  MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, movies,
                               R.layout.stickymessages, new String[] {"comments"}, 
                               new int[]{R.id.textView1});

                           setListAdapter(adapter);
                          ListView lv = getListView();


                         lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                        long id) {



                          }
                            lv.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                    int action = event.getAction();
                                    switch (action) {
                                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                        // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                                        break;

                                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                        // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    // Handle ListView touch events.
                                    v.onTouchEvent(event);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            });




                    }
                });
            }

        }
    class GetDaPid extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {

           }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            }

              protected void onPostExecute(String zoom){
                  MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            new GetDaComments().execute();
                        }
                    });
            }

        }

    /**
     * Receiving push messages
     * */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //  Log.e("broadcast", MainActivity.name);
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());
            Log.v(TAGE, "broadcast?");
            /**
             * Take appropriate action on this message
             * depending upon your app requirement
             * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
             * */

            // Showing received message
            lblMessage.append("New Message: "+ newMessage + "\n");          
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mRegisterTask != null) {
            mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
        }
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
            GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

GCM

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
       displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
       // Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
        ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, registrationId, MainActivity.flat, MainActivity.admin, MainActivity.dummy);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registred
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on receiving a deleted message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }

}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tromto.flat"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.tromto.flat.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.tromto.flat.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"

            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <!-- Login Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="Login Account" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchableActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_searchable"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FlatListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_flat_list"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.tromto.flat" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MsgToflatActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_msg_toflat"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisteradminActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registeradmin" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post the manifest file and let me know if MainActivity is opened when you click on notification or nothing is happening

Comment: Added the manifest. So, when I click on the notification the MainActivity is opened, just that the textView that is supposed to show the Notification isn't updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the TextView after you initialize it

```
lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);
```

As you are making notification and putting the value with the key "message", so you need to retrieve the value though the same key "message"

```
lblMessage.append("New Message: "+ i.getStringExtra("message") + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_push_message);
String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
txtMessage.setText(message);
```